# Doctrine ORM zend framework entitymanager findby multiple conditions

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I'm querying the database with 2 findby's, is there a way to do it in one findby with 2 conditions?

```
$this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneByConfirmtoken($token)
        && $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneById($id)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
->findBy([
    'property1' => 'value1',
    'property2' => 'value2',
])
```

See [the docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-simple-conditions) about using conditions

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the array of values to findBy method. I also recommend you write your own repositories in specific cases. It is useful for more complex queries. In this case it would be looks like:

```
public function findOneByIdAndConfirmationToken(int $userId, string $confirmationToken): ?User
{
    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('u')
        ->from(User::class, 'u')
        ->where('u.id = :userId')
        ->andWhere('u.confirmationToken = :confirmationToken')
        ->setParameter('userId', $userId, PDO::PARAM_INT)
        ->setParameter('confirmationToken', $confirmationToken, PDO::PARAM_STR)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```